# Graph a custom function in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to graph a custom function including `min` and `max` :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: max(0, x)
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
y = f(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Result:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Some help will be welcome

Comment: Usual problem of calling a scalar function with a vector. See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661978/plot-discrete-distribution-using-np-linspace

Answer (score 5):

use vectorized [`np.clip()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) instead of `f` - this way you can set both lower (`a_min`) and upper (`a_max`) boundaries in one step:

```
y = np.clip(x, a_min=0, a_max=None)
```

or try to vectorize your scalar funcion:

```
In [146]: x = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, 10**6)

In [147]: x.shape
Out[147]: (1000000,)

In [148]: vf = np.vectorize(f)

In [149]: %timeit [f(i) for i in x]
1.46 s ± 5.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [150]: %timeit vf(x)
1.03 s ± 8.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Undoubtedly faster than my list comp for big problems, but it's an optimisation specific to this particular problem, not a general `lambda`.

Comment: Thank you, my final custom function is not only based on min/max, it contains min/max

Comment: @alex, i'd suggest you to post your function - if it can be vectorized in a way that it uses fast (vectorized) ufuncs - it might be much faster compared to list comprehension approach...

Comment: @roganjosh, list comprehension might be faster for small arrays ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `max`, use `np.maximum`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = lambda x: np.maximum(0, x)
x = np.linspace(-10,10)
y = f(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**:

In case of more complex functions, look out for the `numpy` equivalents of the functions you intend to use. Most of the time the names are the same as in the `math` module, e.g. `math.sin` would become `np.sin` etc. However, as in the example, `max` should be replaced by `np.maximum` not `np.max`, the latter of which returns the maximum value of an `np.ndarray`.

Comment: This is the most elegant, IMO, solution to the particular problem but the question is "Graph a custom function in python" and this just addresses the single case that was given by the OP.

Comment: @roganjosh Quite true, but on the other hand, `numpy` provides a lot of vectorised versions of mathematical functions. At least all the functions in `math` are also defined in `numpy`, so this example can easily be extended.

Comment: The idea would of course be to replace all the `max` from the function by `np.maximum`. Interestingly `np.clip` seems to be a little faster than `np.maximum`. Using `np.vectorize` on the initial function is 100 times slower than any of the numpy functions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could it be that `np.maximum` and `np.minimum` are implemented using `np.clip`? That would explain the better performance.

Comment: I have no idea. By far the fastest solution would be to compare inplace, `def f(x): x[x<=0] = 0; return x`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a list comprehension to get the corresponding `y` value for every value of `x`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: max(0, x)
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
y = [f(i) for i in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it useful to define one function that can be called using one line of code, so now I can plot any function (assuming the invoked components are valid, e.g. log is loaded as "from math import log", or is expressed as "math.log", and that the function can be evaluated over the specified range):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
from math import log

def plot_func(x,f):
  # x = tuple defining range of x
  # f = string defining function to plot, in terms of x
  x = np.linspace(x[0],x[1],201)
  y = list(map(lambda x: eval(f), x))
  plt.close()
  plt.title('f(x) = ' + f)
  plt.plot(x,y, 'b')

plot_func(x=(0, 1), f = '60 * (x**3) * (1-x)**2')
```

Generates:

[image]

It's just nice to avoid formal definition of the function being plotted, and to be able to reuse this to plot anything with one simple line to be tweaked.